# how to fix a problem where a django template isn't displayed correctly in the email

Tags: django, email, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-email

I have a template which is supposed to display an html template for a reset password. I do receive the email, but the result is not the template itself but the code inside the template.

I've tried to see if there was any error in the html file, but i didn't find any. I use the django-rest-framework for sending the e-mail

What is inside the Template is only HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Réinitialisation de votre mot de passe</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">

...
...
...
```

what is inside settings.py :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ""


if config('USE_SENDGRID', cast=bool):
    EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"
    SENDGRID_API_KEY = config('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
    SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG = False
else:
    #EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

I do receive the email but i receive the code inside the file, not the compiled html code.
Thank you

Comment: You need to show the code that is sending this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I use the django-rest-framework for sending the email so i didn"t had to write any code appart of setting the variables in settings.py

Comment: But DRF doesn't just send mail by itself. You must have some code telling it to do that, and specifying the contents. Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code you used to send the email, it's hard to know what's wrong. It looks like you are sending the mail with something like `send_mail`. To send mail in html format use [EmailMultiAlternatives](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types)

For example:

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from, to = 'Hello World', 'noreply@example.com', 'example@example.com'
text = 'hello'
html = '<h1>Hello</h1><p>world</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text, from, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html, "text/html")
msg.send()
```